# Area51 tab selection should be remembered for each proposal individually

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Area51 votes/newest/on-topic/off-topic tabs should be remembered for each proposal, and not globally.

Our interest in a given proposal might be at a different stage.  When surfing the Area51 site it bugs me that the active tab is whatever the active tab was for the previous proposal, and not when I was last looking at that particular proposal.

Comment: I'd want the opposite; that is, the current behavior.  That's how other sorting tabs work within a single SE site.

Comment: Stop fretting over things like this and follow my proposal.